# Visual studio 2015 infectado?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Tengo un problema con mi Visual Studio, da errores aleatorios sin sentido, y uno de ellos que me llamó bastante la atención fue el siguiente,

> Archivo ya abierto no se puede volvera utilizar `mysql_error_log.txt`

Me pareció raro porque el archivo no se encontraba en el directorio del servidor sino en el directorio del proyecto, cuando lo abrí encontré el siguiente texto:

> Hi :)

Entonces tengo un archivo que no corresponde en el directorio del proyecto y este tiene un texto bastante peculiar, supongo que me han infectado el ordenador, asi que pague un antivirus, el cual funciona muy bien, pero no encontró ningún elemento raro, es decir amenaza o malware, asi que quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar con este problema, si a alguien le ha pasado no se, tengo el que terminar esta tarde el sistema y lo tengo infectado, **¿alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo, a alguien le ha pasado?** puedo proceder de alguna manera especial no se, espero su respuesta muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formateo directo y reinstalacion, ademas, te recomiendo actualizar a visual studio 2017, consume menos recursos que el 2015, y tiene un par de mejoras de estabilidad principalmente

Comment: utilizo el 2015 porque se puede programar para windows xp todavia

Comment: aunque no recomiendo usar windows xp en estas fechas, pero entonces de igual manera te recomiendo formatear tu pc y reinstalarlo

Comment: la respuesta me suena excesiva.. pero igual, @BernardoHarreguy que te impide programar en vs2017 para xp? si vos decis el framework de destino?

Comment: windows xp, tengo clientes que lo utilizan, y el sistema corre bajo net framework 4.0

Comment: y si podes selecccionar como target el framework de destino.. hasta lo podrias hacer para 2.. eso ya hace tiempo que funciona en VS... @BernardoHarreguy

Comment: ademas, a partir de junio, supuestamente deja de funcionar las conexiones a red con framework 4.0 y 4.5, por problemas de TLS 1, por lo que quedarian practicamente inutiles las aplicaciones

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue borrar todas las dll, copiar todo el proyecto sin las dll,Reinstalar windows e instalar Visual Studio 2017, descargar las dll que me faltaban , de esta manera funciono correctamente